# Get value from recursive table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

```
ParentNode | Node      | Children
---------- | --------- | ---------
NULL       | Parent_1  | true
Parent_1   | Child_1   | true
Child_1    | Child_2   | true
Child_2    | Value1    | false
NULL       | Parent_2  | true
Parent_2   | Child_1   | true
Child_1    | Value2    | false
```

I need a function that returns the value path:

```
select Node, MyFunction(Node) as Path from myTable where Children = 'false'
```

The expected result is:

```
Node   | Path
------ | ---------
Value1 | Parent_1/Child_1/Child_2
Value2 | Parent_2/Child_1
```

any ideas?

Comment: have you tried anything at all?

Comment: What defines  order ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem with this code:

```
;WITH children AS
(
   SELECT 
     ParentNode,
    CAST(ISNULL(ParentNode + '/' ,'')  + node AS VARCHAR(4000)) AS PathValue
   FROM dashConfigurationSchema
   WHERE node =  'Value1'
 UNION ALL
   SELECT 
     t.ParentNode,
     list= CAST(ISNULL(t.ParentNode  + '/' ,'')  + d.PathValue AS VARCHAR(4000))
   FROM dashConfigurationSchema t
   INNER JOIN children  AS d
        ON t.Node = d.ParentNode
 )

SELECT PathValue from children c WHERE ParentNode IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it, I've not tested it.

```
WITH tree AS
(
    SELECT c1.Node, c1.ParentNode, [level] = 1, path = cast(c1.Node as varchar(300))
    FROM dbo.[table] c1
    WHERE c1.ParentNode = 'value 1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c2.Node, c2.ParentNode, [level] = tree.[level] + 1, 
           Path = Cast(tree.path + '/' + c2.Node as varchar(300))
    FROM dbo.[table] c2 INNER JOIN tree ON tree.Node = c2.ParentNode
)
SELECT tree.Node, tree.path
FROM tree
Order by path
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first define a function that calls itself recursively:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getFullPath]
(
    @node_name nvarchar(50)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @parent_name as nvarchar(50)
    declare @full_path as nvarchar(max)

    select  
    @parent_name = parentnode,
    @node_name = node
    from tree (nolock)
    where node = @node_name

    set @full_path = @node_name

    if(isnull(@parent_name,'') <> '')
    begin
        set @full_path = dbo.getFullPath(@parent_name) + '\' + @full_path
    end

    return @full_path
END
GO
```

Then just use it in a query:

```
select
node,
dbo.getFullPath(node)
from tree
```

Comment: I would not recommend this as a good approach. Scalar functions are notoriously poor from a performance standpoint and calling them recursively  can be horrendous. A recursive cte would be better from a performance perspective. Also, I would not suggest tossing NOLOCK hints on queries like this. It can be far more sinister than simply dirty reads. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/